# Passing an event method between siblings component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am practicing in ReactJS and I have a trouble in passing a method between 2 sibling component. I have created React app which has 3 component: `MainPage` is the parent, `FirstPage` and `SecondPage` are two children. In `FirstPage` component there is a header with some text and `SecondPage` component has a button. My main goal is to pass the change-header method I defined in `FirstPage`, through `MainPage` component, to `SecondPage` component, so that when I click on the button that event method is fired.

I follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17 to build my app. I also use `react-router-dom` in `MainPage` to display two page: one for `FirstPage`, another for `SecondPage`

Here is my `FirstPage` component:

```js
import React from 'react'
class FirstPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            msg: 'First page'
        }

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.callBack(this.changeText.bind(this))
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "first">
                <h2>{this.state.msg}</h2>
            </div>
        )
    }
    changeText(){
         {/* event method I defined to change the header text*/}
        this.setState({msg: 'Text changed !!'})
        this.props.history.push('/first')
    }

}
export default FirstPage
```

and `MainPage` component:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'
import FirstPage from '../component/FirstPage'
import SecondPage from '../component/SecondPage'
class MainPage extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            func : null
        }
    }
    myCallBack(callFunc){
        this.setState({func: callFunc})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "main">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path = "/first" render = {(props) => <FirstPage  {...props} callBack = {this.myCallBack.bind(this)} />} />
                        <Route path = "/second" render = {(props) => <SecondPage  {...props} myFunc = {this.state.func}/>} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default MainPage
```

Follow the tutorial, I defined the property `func` inside `MainPage` state to store the event method from `FirstPage`. The `myCallBack` method is used to change the property of state. And I pass that method to the `FirstPage` by using `callBack = {this.myCallBack.bind(this)}`. So in the `FirstPage`, when the `this.props.callBack(this.changeText.bind(this))` called, the event method will be stored into `MainPage` state

And finally my `SecondPage` commponent:

```js
import React from 'react'
class SecondPage extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "second">
                <h2>Second page</h2>
                <button onClick = {this.props.myFunc}> Click here to change</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default SecondPage
```

App.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import MainPage from './component/MainPage'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className = "App">
       <MainPage/>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

I simply pass the `this.state.func` that store my event to `SecondPage` through props. And I think this should be work: when I click the button, React will redirect to the 'FirstPage' and change the header field. But in fact when I clicked, nothing happen. Can anyone show me which part I did wrong ?

Comment: I don't think, this is the right way to do it. You might want to use some global state for this (Redux or even browser localStorage would do). Also there are couple of issue in code too,  where are you giving state header value to FirstPage.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Quang.**

In order to do this, that is a possible approach you can follow:

- For any shared data between two siblings of a parent component, we basically put that shared data in the closest parent, which in this case `MainPage`

**Further:**

1. The content you want show in `FirstPage` and change by `SecondPage` should exist in the state of the parent component `MainPage`
2. Pass the content to the `FirstPage` as a prop, such like `content={this.state.content}`
3. The function that changes the content `changeText` should be inside `MainPage` because it will be changing the specific state that is sent as a prop to the `FirstPage`
4. Function, when invoked by `SecondPage` should be changing the state of the `MainPage`, which is passed to the `FirstPage` as the content of the header.

**Solution:**

**- FirstPage:**

```
// Re-write as a functional component, because we won't be using lifecycle methods, thus, no need for it to be class component.
import React from 'react'

const FirstPage = (props) => (
  <div className = "first">
    <h2>{props.msg}</h2>
  </div>
);

export default FirstPage
```

**- SecondPage:**

```
// Re-write as a functional component, because we won't be using lifecycle methods, thus, no need for it to be class component.
import React from 'react'

const SecondPage = (props) => (
  <div className = "second">
    <h2>Second page</h2>
    <button onClick = {props.changeMsg}> Click here to change</button>
  </div>
)

export default SecondPage
```

**- MainPage:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import FirstPage from "../component/FirstPage";
import SecondPage from "../component/SecondPage";
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      msg: '', //added msg that is shown in FirstPage
    };
  }


  // Added the function changeMsg to modify msg value in the state by the button onClick event from SecondPage.
  changeMsg(){
      {/* event method I defined to change the header text*/}
    this.setState({ msg: 'Text changed !!' })
    this.props.history.push('/first')
  }

  // Cleared some un-used functions.
  // passed msg for FirstPage as a Prop
  // passed changeMsg to SecondPage as a Prop

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/first"
              render={props => (
                <FirstPage {...props} msg={this.state.msg} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/second"
              render={props => (
                <SecondPage {...props} changeMsg={this.changeMsg.bind(this)} />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

Comment: Wow your code is very clear and simple to me. Thank you very much !!